# How to find maximum of bezier curve

Tags: bezier

Is there an easy way to find the maximum of a bezier curve/path?

My intention is to draw a vertical line where the curve has its maximum.
I did it "by hand" and it does the job, but I'd appreciate a more elegant solution.

here is my code so far.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10, thick]

\draw[name path=cons] (-0.5, 0) .. controls (-0.2, 0.4) and (0.45, 0.6) .. (0.5, 0);
\path[name path=line1] (-1, 0.1) -- (1, 0.1);
\draw[name intersections={of=line1 and cons}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);

\path[name path=line2] (0.175, 0) -- (0.175, 0.4);
\path[name path=intersection1, name intersections={of=line2 and line1}] (intersection-1) coordinate (int1);
\path[name path=intersection2, name intersections={of=line2 and cons}] (intersection-1) coordinate (int2);

\draw (int1) -- (int2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: bèzier curve and two lins]

Comment: This task is easier to solve in a “real” programming language. For example, the LuaLaTeX package `bezierplot` may be useful (“It finds special points such as extreme points and inflection points and reduces the number of used points.”). Using TeX’s built-in “language” can be tedious.

Comment: The other option is to dig into the math of how a Bezier curve is defined.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Thanks for pointing that out! I'm not familiar with LuaLaTeX, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes I might be able to do compute it, but not without stuffing a lot of math operations in LaTeX! Well my pictures serves me well for now. I'll post my solution, when I find a good one.